# Whitelisting app users in Google Play Store (outside the organisation)

Tags: android, google-play

My goal is to place application in the Google Play Store and let only certain users download it (access would be granted by their Google account). One of the possible solutions is to use Google Play Private Channel (https://support.google.com/a/answer/2494992?hl=en) but then users' accounts are limited to certain domain, which is in my case impossible. What are the other options?

Comment: An [alpha/beta test group](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using Closed Beta tests in Google Play. [Here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en) you can find a detailed info.